# Removing a class when the menu is collapsed in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had to add a class .bgGradient when the navbar is expanded because the client wanted an image in the navbar and the text wasn't easily legible with it. So I added a slight gradient behind the navbar. But when it's collapsed, the gradient looks weird so I wanted to get rid of it.

Is there any way to get rid of the class .bgGradient only when the navbar is collapsed?

```css
 .navbar {
   margin: -30px 0 15px 0;
 }

 .navbar ul {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
 }

 .navbar .nav-item .nav-link {
   color: #FFF;
   font-family: "Helvetica," sans-serif;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 14px;
   display: inline-flex;
   padding: 0px;
 }

 .bgGradient {
   background-color: rgba(54, 203, 216, 0.8);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 5px #36CBD8;
 }

 .bgGradient2 {
   background-color: rgba(16, 188, 185, 0.5);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #10BCB9;
 }

 .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
   color: white;
 }

 .custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
   border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 }

 .custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 0.7)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" class="no-js">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>


    <div class="sticky-top">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-3">
        <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-around" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          BOOKS
        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="brandingsutra">Branding Sutra</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          LEARNING LAB
        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Workshops</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Podcast</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Classes</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle bgGradient2" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          SERVICES
        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Coaching</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mindfulness</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle bgGradient" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          FREEBIES
        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Challenge</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">DIY Copywriting</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle bgGradient" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          ABOUT
        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Merry Carole</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Branding Powers</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Here's a fiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/3pnb1byp/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bootstrap 3** navbar breakpoint is at 991px so you can use media queries to change your collapsed navbar.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
 .bgGradient {
   background-color: transparent;
   box-shadow: none;
 }

 .bgGradient2 {
   background-color: transparent;
   box-shadow: none;
 }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g3hg27j0/

Answer (score 0):

As you are using **navbar-expand-md**the class in the nav would make this Navbar collapse vertically (and **show the toggle icon**) at the **medium (md) breakpoint of 992px**. But for some reason, **your breakpoint** actually **works** for **screen width less than 768px**.

And to get **rid of the gradient**. You can use the **media query with min-width** so your gradient class will only work until your minimum width breakpoint. And also you **don't** need to **add additional CSS**.

Below check CSS part I set the media query with min-width: 768px so when device screen is less than 768px gradient class will not work.

```css
 .navbar {
   margin: -30px 0 15px 0;
 }

 .navbar ul {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
 }

 .navbar .nav-item .nav-link {
   color: #FFF;
   font-family: "Helvetica," sans-serif;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 14px;
   display: inline-flex;
   padding: 0px;
 }
 @media only screen and (min-width:768px){
  .bgGradient {
    background-color: rgba(54, 203, 216, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 5px #36CBD8;
  }

  .bgGradient2 {
    background-color: rgba(16, 188, 185, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #10BCB9;
  }
 }
 .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
   color: white;
 }
   
 .custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
   border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 }

 .custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 0.7)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" class="no-js">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>


    <div class="sticky-top">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-3">
        <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-around" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          BOOKS
        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="brandingsutra">Branding Sutra</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          LEARNING LAB
        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Workshops</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Podcast</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Classes</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle bgGradient2" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          SERVICES
        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Coaching</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mindfulness</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle bgGradient" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          FREEBIES
        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Challenge</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">DIY Copywriting</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle bgGradient" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          ABOUT
        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Merry Carole</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Branding Powers</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```